# why does code produce <function __main__.income_tax(income, status='single')> instead of a number

Tags: python

This is a tax calculator that calculates tax owed based on income and if your single or married.

When I run the code using income = 10000 and status single I get `<function __main__.income_tax(income, status='single')>` instead of `1000`.

**code**:

```
def income_tax(income, status = "single"):
     if status == 'single':
        income_tax_single(income)
        tax_owed = income_tax 
        
     elif status == 'married filing jointly':
        income_tax_married_jointly(income)
        tax_owed = income_tax
     else:
        print("status must be either 'single' or 'married filing jointly'. You entered 'status = ", status," '")
        return
        
     return tax_owed

def income_tax_married_jointly(income):
    
    income = round(income) ## round the income to nearest integer

    if income <= 19750:
        tax_bracket = 0.1
        income_tax = 0.1 * income
    elif (income >= 19751) and (income <= 80250):
        tax_bracket = 0.12
        income_tax = 1975 + 0.12 * (income - 19750)
    elif (income >= 80251) and (income <= 171050):
        tax_bracket = 0.22
        income_tax = 9235 + 0.22 * (income - 80250)
    elif (income >= 171051) and (income <= 326600):
        tax_bracket = 0.24
        income_tax = 29211 + 0.24 * (income - 171050)
    elif (income >= 326601) and (income <= 414700):
        tax_bracket = 0.32
        income_tax = 66543 + 0.32 * (income - 326601)
    elif (income >= 414701) and (income <= 622050):
        tax_bracket = 0.35
        income_tax = 94735 + 0.35 * (income - 414700)
    elif income >= 622051:
        tax_bracket = 0.37
        income_tax = 167307.50 + 0.37 * (income - 622050)
    
    return income_tax, tax_bracket

def income_tax_single(income, round_income = True):
    
    if round_income == True:
        income = round(income) # round to nearest integer
    else:
        income = income # do not round it
    
    if income <= 9875:
        tax_bracket = 0.1
        income_tax = 0.1 * income
    elif (income >= 9876
         ) and (income <= 40125):
        tax_bracket = 0.12
        income_tax = 987.50 + 0.12 * (income - 9875)
    elif (income >= 40126) and (income <= 85525):
        tax_bracket = 0.22
        income_tax = 4617.50 + 0.22 * (income - 40125)
    elif (income >= 85526) and (income <= 163300):
        tax_bracket = 0.24
        income_tax = 14605.50 + 0.24 * (income - 85525)
    elif (income >= 163301) and (income <= 207350):
        tax_bracket = 0.32
        income_tax = 33271.50 + 0.32 * (income - 163300)
    elif (income >= 207351) and (income <= 518400):
        tax_bracket = 0.35
        income_tax = 47367.50 + 0.35 * (income - 207350)
    elif income >= 518401:
        tax_bracket = 0.37
        income_tax = 156235 + 0.37 * (income - 518400)
    
    
    return income_tax, tax_bracket
```

Comment: this code doesn't produce *any* output. I *suspect* (**why make us guess, why not just tell us?**) that you are calling `income_tax(1000)`. In that function, you assign `tax_owed = income_tax` in both branches, then return `tax_owed`, but in that scope `income_tax` is a global variable referring to **a function**.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
tax_owed = income_tax
```

you're setting `tax_owed` to the function named `income_tax`.

You need to assign the values returned by `income_tax_single` or `income_tax_married_jointly` to variables. You can't use the variables that were local to those functions.

```
def income_tax(income, status = "single"):
     if status == 'single':
        tax_owed, tax_bracket = income_tax_single(income)
     elif status == 'married filing jointly':
        tax_owed, tax_bracket = income_tax_married_jointly(income)
     else:
        print("status must be either 'single' or 'married filing jointly'. You entered 'status = ", status," '")
        return
        
     return tax_owed
```

Try to avoid reusing names, it makes things confusing. If you have a function named `income_tax`, don't also have variable with the same name. If you had used different variable names in the `income_tax_XXX` functions, you would have gotten a more useful error telling you that the variable doesn't exist when you try to use it in `income_tax`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're assigning the function object `income_tax_single` or `income_tax_married_jointly` to the variable `tax_owed` instead of the result of the function call.

To fix the issue, make sure you call the functions correctly by using parentheses operator `()` and capture the tax value properly.

Here's a modified income_tax function to fix the problem:

```py
def income_tax(income, status = "single"):
    if status == 'single':
        # Get the first returned value and disregard the second
        tax_owed, _ = income_tax_single(income)
    elif status == 'married filing jointly':
        tax_owed, _ = income_tax_married_jointly(income)
    else:
        print("status must be either 'single' or 'married filing jointly'. You entered 'status = ", status," '")
        return
        
    return tax_owed
```

With this fix, if you run:

```py
print(income_tax(10000, 'single'))
```

You'll get `1000`.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am relatively new to programming; however, based on the snippets you provided, I believe returning two values through a function is one of the issues causing complications. You should just return the **income_tax**; I don't believe you need to return **tax_bracket**. That way, the function call will be easier to operate with : ).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).